# Listing equations

Tags: lists

I want to list some equations like the following
[image]

I tried doing

```
\begin{align*}
a)\ (1+i)^2     &       b)\ \frac{1}{i} \ c) \frac{1}{1+i}      &       d)\ (2+3i)(3-4i)        &       e) (1+i)(1-2i)  &       f) i^5+i^{16}\\g)\ -1   &       h)\ -3i &       i)\ 1+i+i^2+i^3 &       j)\ \frac{1}{2}(1+i)(1-^{-8})   &       k)\ \frac{1+i}{\sqrt(2)}        &       l)\ \frac{1}{(1+i)^2}
\end{align*}
```

but I didn't get the output I wanted.
Thanks!

Comment: This is task for `tasks` package` ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use an inline list with the package `enumitem`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{enumerate*}[label=\textit{\alph*}), itemjoin=\qquad]
    \item \((1 + i)^2\)
    \item \(\dfrac{1}{i}\)
    \item \(\dfrac{1}{1 + i}\)
    \item \((2 + 3i)(3 - 4i)\)
    \item \((1 + i)(1 - 2i)\)
    \item \(i^5 + i^{16}\)
    \item \(-1\)
    \item \(-3i\)
    \item \(1 + i + i^2 + i^3\)
    \item \(\dfrac{1}{2}(1 + i)(1 - i^{-8})\)
    \item \(\dfrac{1 + i}{\sqrt{2}}\)
    \item \(\dfrac{1}{(1 + i)^2}\)
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the effort and for the itemjoin :-)